# How do I apply a composed function to each object in a list using Ramda?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm building a simple app using RamdaJS that aims to take a list of objects that represent U.S. states, and for each state, it should calculate the number of electoral votes and add that value as a new property to each object, called `electoralVotes`. The basic gist of the calculation itself (as inaccurate as it may be) is to divide the population by `600000`, round that number down, and if the rounded-down number is `0`, round it up to `1`.

For simplicity, the array of `states` only includes a state name and population for each state:

```js
const states = [
  { state: 'Alabama', population: 4833722 },
  { state: 'Alaska', population: 735132 },
  { state: 'Arizona', population: 6626624 },
  // ... etc.
];
```

I created a function called `getElectoralVotesForState` that is created with nested levels of composition (A composed function that is built using another composed function). This function takes a state object, examines its `population` property, then calculates and returns the corresponding number of electoral votes.

```js
const R = require('ramda');

// This might not be factually accurate, but it's a ballpark anyway
const POP_PER_ELECTORAL_VOTE = 600000;

const populationLens = R.lensProp("population");

// Take a number (population) and calculate the number of electoral votes
// If the rounded-down calculation is 0, round it up to 1
const getElectoralVotes = R.pipe(
  R.divide(R.__, POP_PER_ELECTORAL_VOTE),
  Math.floor,
  R.when(R.equals(0), R.always(1))
);

// Take a state object and return the electoral votes
const getElectoralVotesForState = R.pipe(
  R.view(populationLens),
  getElectoralVotes
);
```

If I want to pass in a single state to the `getElectoralVotesForState`  function, it works fine:

```js
const alabama = { state: 'Alabama', population: 4833722 };
const alabamaElectoralVotes = getElectoralVotesForState(alabama); // Resolves to 8
```

While this seems to work for a single object, I can't seem to get this to apply to an *array* of objects. My guess is that the solution might look something like this:

```js
const statesWithElectoralVotes = R.map(
  R.assoc("electoralVotes", getElectoralVotesForState)
)(states);
```

This *does* add an `electoralVotes` property to each state, but it's a function and not a resolved value. I'm sure it's just a silly thing I'm getting wrong here, but I can't figure it out.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

To apply a function to to an array of items use `R.map`. Since you want the value you don't need to `R.assoc`:

```js
const POP_PER_ELECTORAL_VOTE = 600000;

const populationLens = R.lensProp("population");

const getElectoralVotes = R.pipe(
  R.divide(R.__, POP_PER_ELECTORAL_VOTE),
  Math.floor,
  R.when(R.equals(0), R.always(1))
);

const getElectoralVotesForState = R.pipe(
  R.view(populationLens),
  getElectoralVotes
);

const mapStates = R.map(getElectoralVotesForState);

const states = [{"state":"Alabama","population":4833722},{"state":"Alaska","population":735132},{"state":"Arizona","population":6626624}];

const result = mapStates(states);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

In addition, the lens is a bit redundant here, take the value of population using `R.prop`. I would also replace `R.when` with `R.max`.

```js
const POP_PER_ELECTORAL_VOTE = 600000;

const getElectoralVotesForState = R.pipe(
  R.prop('population'),
  R.divide(R.__, POP_PER_ELECTORAL_VOTE),
  Math.floor,
  R.max(1)
);

const mapStates = R.map(getElectoralVotesForState);

const states = [{"state":"Alabama","population":4833722},{"state":"Alaska","population":735132},{"state":"Arizona","population":6626624}];

const result = mapStates(states);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

To add the property to each object, you'll need to get the value from the object, and then add it as a property to the object. This means that we need to use 2 functions - **f** (`R.assoc`) & **g** (`getElectoralVotesForState`), and apply both of them to the object - **x**, but one of them (`R.assoc`) also need the result of the other function.

you'll need to apply `getElectoralVotesForState` on the object to get the number, (g(x)) and then take the result, and it to the object (

To add the `electoralVotes` you can use `R.chain` in conjunction with `R.assoc`. When `R.chain` is applied to function - `R.chain(f, g)(x)` is equivalent to `f(g(x), x)`. In your case

- f - `assoc`
- g - `getElectoralVotesForState`
- x - the object

The combined function - `R.chain(R.assoc('electoralVotes'), getElectoralVotesForState)` becomes `assoc('electoralVotes')(getElectoralVotesForState(object), object)`.

Example:

```js
const POP_PER_ELECTORAL_VOTE = 600000;

const getElectoralVotesForState = R.pipe(
  R.prop('population'),
  R.divide(R.__, POP_PER_ELECTORAL_VOTE),
  Math.floor,
  R.max(1)
);

const mapStates = R.map(
  R.chain(R.assoc("electoralVotes"), getElectoralVotesForState)
);

const states = [{"state":"Alabama","population":4833722},{"state":"Alaska","population":735132},{"state":"Arizona","population":6626624}];

const result = mapStates(states);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked up `chain` in the Ramda API docs and I still find it confusing. How does it work and why can’t this example work without it? Also, is the lens truly redundant if it can de-couple the property name from the function pipeline definition? It might not be particularly necessary or useful, but is it technically redundant?

Comment: I've added more information about using R.chain in your case. Your function's logic is very coupled to a specific object, so I wouldn't bother with a lens. If you are going to use it on other property names , the lens would indeed be useful.

Comment: Okay, I understand now that `chain(assoc(“newProp”), someFun)` in a pipe would effectively be like calling `assoc(“newProp”)(someFunc(obj)`. I have a couple of questions about that: 1.) Is this the main way to accomplish this kind of thing in Ramda? In vanilla JS, it’s as simple as `a.map(o => ({ …o, newProp: f() }))` 2.) Is this the primary way that `chain` is normally used? The API docs say that it’s the equivalent of what other libraries call `flatMap` and that seems totally different. 3.) If we wanted to just update an existing prop for each state, would `evolve` be easier to use instead?

Comment: 1. In vanilla JS you'll need `a.map(o => ({ …o, newProp: f(o) }))`, (note the `f(o)`) which is very similar to what Ramda is doing. R.chain is used as flatMap but also as a functions combinator (@ScottSauyet can probably explain it better then me). 2. There are different ways to do this - using `R.chain(R.mergeRight, R.applySpec({ newProp: fn }))` for example, or using a lens. However, R.evolve won't work here, since the value is created from other properties and not evolved from the current value.

Answer (score 1):

I think Ori Drori answers your question well.  I have no suggested improvements.  But I want to show that it's not too hard to code the current apportionment method used for the U.S. Congress, the [Huntington-Hill Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntington%E2%80%93Hill_method):

```js
// Huntington-Hill apportionment method
const apportion = (total) => (pops) =>
  huntingtonHill (total - pops.length, pops .map (pop => ({...pop, seats: 1})))

// method of equal proportions
const huntingtonHill = (toFill, seats, state = nextSeat (seats)) =>
  toFill <= 0
    ? seats
    : huntingtonHill (toFill - 1, seats .map (s => s.state == state ? {...s, seats: s.seats + 1} : s))

// find state to assign the next seat
const nextSeat = (seats) => 
  seats 
    .map (({state, population, seats}) => [state, population * Math.sqrt(1 / (seats * (seats + 1)))])
    .sort (([_, a], [_1, b]) => b - a) 
    [0] [0] // ideally, use a better max implementation that sort/head, but low priority

// convert census data to expected object format
const restructure = results => 
  results 
    .slice (1) // remove header
    .map (([population, state]) => ({state, population})) // make objects
    .filter (({state}) => ! ['District of Columbia', 'Puerto Rico'] .includes (state)) // remove non-states
    .sort (({state: s1}, {state: s2}) => s1 < s2 ? -1 : s1 > s2 ? 1 : 0) // alphabetize
    
fetch ('https://api.census.gov/data/2021/pep/population?get=POP_2021,NAME&for=state:*')
  .then (res => res.json())
  .then (restructure)
  .then (apportion (435))
  .then (console .log)
  .catch (console .warn)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here we call the U.S. Census API to fetch the populations of each state, remove Washington DC and Puerto Rico, reformat these results to your `{state, population}` input format, and then call `apportion (435)` with the array of values.  (If you have the data already in that format, you can just call `apportion (435)`), and it will assign one seat to each state and then use the Huntington-Hill method to assign the remaining seats.

It does this by continually calling `nextSeat`, which divides each state's population by the geometric mean of its current number of seats and the next higher number, then choosing the state with the largest value.

This does not use Ramda for anything.  Perhaps we would clean this up slightly with some Ramda functions (for example, replacing `pop => ({...pop, seats: 1})` with `assoc('seat', 1)`), but it would not likely be a large gain.  I saw this question because I pay attention to the Ramda tag.  But the point here is that the actual current method of apportionment is not that difficult to implement, if you happen to be interested.

You can see how this technique is used to compare different sized houses in an [old gist](https://gist.github.com/CrossEye/5a7ee1dd6e91f3cc0f4a12eca8128b88) of mine.